# Facing issue while configuring Confluent kafka with Azure databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I am newbie  to Azure databrciks and this forum. I am actually carrying out exercise for steaming Confluent Kafka on Azure databricks. I am able to stream the content on spark. However, there is slight problem as I am exposing username and password in the program. I would rather passed this through the variable(or Azure key-vault). I have tried passing username and password using variable but this approach is not working. I am getting error saying that 'unable to create Kafka consumer'. Can you please let me know how I can proceed? I am using scala for this.

```
val streamingInputDF = spark
.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", host)
.option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
.option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"AAAAAA\" password=\BBBBB\";")
.option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https")
.option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
.option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
.option("subscribe", "Test")
.load()
```

This is how I want to pass but not working :-

```
val streamingInputDF = spark
.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", host)
.option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
.option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", f"kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=$username password=$password";")
.option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https")
.option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
.option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
.option("subscribe", "streaming_test_6")
.load()
```

Comment: You're mixing languages.  That's a Scala statement, but you're using Python-style string interpolation., `f"..."`, instead of Scala-style, eg `s"Hello, $name"` See https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html  Mixing up Scala and Python is _incredibly common_ in Databricks as half the docs and samples are in one language, and half in the other.

Comment: I have tried that approach as well. but I am still getting error Failed to construct kafka consumer

Answer (score 0):

You need to check below points:

1. Make sure you have kafka-clients jar in your class path.
2. Make sure you have compatible version of kafka and spark installed

You can refer [article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/consume-avro-data-from-kafka-topics-and-secured-schema-registry-with-databricks-confluent-cloud-on-azure/#step-5) by ANGELA CHU, GIANLUCA NATALI AND  CAIO MORENO, where detailed description is given.

[Scala Notebook link](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-azure-examples/blob/master/databricks-blog/ConfluentKafkaAvroBlogScala.dbc?raw=true)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all who tried to provide suggestion. I am able to resolve issue. Below is the line where changes are required

```
.option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config",
   "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"" + confluentApiKey + "\"password=\"" + confluentSecret + "\";")
```